# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I had GCM in my App. After an update of the Android SDK Tools my App crashed. I'll get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(24175): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar
```

I searched for fixes, I proceed thinks like;

- Import .jar file manually
- Add .jar to build path
- etc.

Who has the fix for this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I've just solved the problem with my app.

Follow below steps to resolve the problem:

1. Right click on Project->Build Path=> **Configure Build Path** and then **Order and Exports**
2. Now check the Android Private Libraries checkbox.
3. Refresh ,Clean and Run..here you go!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this error after updating the Android SDK tools as well, but I was able to compile and install my application from the command line. If you have Ant installed you can use the commands in your applications directory:

```
android update project --name NameOfYourProject -p . --target android-17

ant clean debug

ant installd
```

I am using Windows 7, jdk1.7, and I had just updated to Android SDK Tools 22.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are exporting the library.